# Freemarker vs AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rendering, freemarker

Does it make sense having a solution that uses both Freemarker and AngularJS?

I tried to convince everyone on my team of switching to Angular, and a more experienced developer than me pointed out that he prefers server-side rendering, which is both arguable and valid. But then he told me that if I still want to use Angular just use it with Freemarker instead of replacing it.

I'm a junior programmer, as far as I can understand they are designed to the same purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I google for Freemarker i realize it is just a templating engine. AngularJS is not a templating engine. Templating engine is just part within this framework. So both of them cannot be compared.

AngularJS is a full fledged framework for creating Single Page Applications (SPA). So if you want just templating capabilities on client side, i suggest you better look for some other light weight libraries.

If you want to use AngularJS you need to decide

- Whether you can structure your app as a SPA
- Does the site needs to be SEO optimized. Which has limited support in Angular or as a matter of fact in any client side framework.
- Ready to use the AngularJS templating engine because it is awesome with its support for oneway\two way active bindings. If you don't use it templating engine you are loosing a lot.

Comment: I know Angular can do more things, this developer told me to use Freemarker to make the initial template on server side and then Angular for the awesome data binding on client side. I just feel it would not be right to use both since Angular is capable of everything. It is a private site so it does not need SEO. Why it should be a single page application if I want to use Angular?

Comment: You can just use the data binding capabilities of of AngularJS but that is a just a part of AngularJS. If you do not use it as SPA then the framework has be re initialized on every page, and remember not use it's $location or $route service.

Comment: Server side template would need to generate interpolation html markers like `{{}}` which would make no sense on server. If you send initial content using server templating library. I suggest you try to create something trivial integrating server and client templating and see if it works.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the needs.

For example, if you want to break your page into individual re-usable components that you can tie based on some logic on the server side, then using freemarker or velocity for building these components makes sense.
The freemarker or velocity templates might in-turn use *angularJS* components that would be rendered on the browser and evaluated on the client side.
The server side templating would give you the ability to design re-usable angular components.

Now, some may try to use the Object component in HTML5 for doing the same thing, but this is not recommended as using Object expects a fully formed HTML element with its own `<html>` opening and closing tag.
Not something that is intended for a small reusable component.

As an example consider having your page header and footer in its own html template file that you would like to tie in for all the pages in your application.

Answer (score 1):

No it clearly does not make sense as they serve very different purposes. All I can think of is that you either misunderstood the more experienced developer or he really has not understood the business case (WHY something is worth using) of using either technology. In my experience as a j2ee developer, I find that many server side developers (experienced or not) may not be too educated on the many new advances recently made in client side development. With Angular you are not limited to SPA. You need an insight into the overall architecture of your current project to determine if its a good fit. There are ways around the SEO issues or you can purchase an SEO solution. But clearly not a best choice if SEO is essential.

Unless it is a team decision and there are clear problems Angular solves for you, I would not suggest getting stuck alone with a new technology that only you know. Keep it as a hobby and when you really understand the best practices and benefits you can then try being an evangelist.

Comment: We are making a backoffice for employees and clients, it is a private page so SEO is not a problem. I am confused about 'it clearly does not make sense as they serve very different purposes', could you further explain?

Comment: Both inject a data model for use in a template. Both use separation of concerns. Angular is not the powerful preprocessor you get in Freemarker. Do you just want to load template partials on page load? Use Angular. Do you want to substitute text with other text use Freemarker. Although FreeMarker has some programming capabilities, it is not a full-blown programming language like Angular.

Comment: Chandermani's suggestion to " I suggest you try to create something trivial integrating server and client templating and see if it works." is great advise but start out by making complete sure what problem you are trying to solve and whether you can solve it using just one of these. Keep it simple...the shoe does not fit every princess. I was a bit to fast to suggest that it makes no sense as I clearly do not understand the problem you face as well as you do.